# The method () was called on null. [Flutter]

Tags: datetime, flutter

In this app, the user will be able to add a task and i wanted to give the option to select the date on which the user wants to save a task (at a later date; one week, a few days from now, etc.). The tasks are displayed in a `pageView.builder` which displays each page according to the date (ex:`initial page: DateTime.now()`). After setting the date, the user should be able to jump to the particular date selected by them in the `showDatePicker` and also display the added task in the selected page (which will also be set according to the date selected date in `showDatePicker`). The controller `_daysPageController.jumpToDay` is the controller which lets the user jump to a desired page.

The date selected by the user is returned in a `DateTime` format in this line :

```
DateTime selecteddate = DateTime.now();
  Future<Null> _selectDate() async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selecteddate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selecteddate)
      setState(() {
        selecteddate = picked;
      });
    _daysPageController.jumpToDay(selecteddate);
  }
```

The `DateTime` `selecteddate` successfully returns the date selected by the user but when i pass it in the `_daysPageController`, i get the error; 
`The method 'jumpToDay' was called on null.`

Could i get a suggestion on how I can pass the `selecteddate` so that the `_daysPageController.jumpToDay()` will only execute after the `selectddate` is set?

I have implemented the `pageView.builder` using this repository :
https://github.com/ZedTheLed/calendar_views

this also contains the `PageController` to jump to a specific page.

Comment: I assume, you got the error for _daysPageController. Please, share your full code.

Comment: unfortunately i do not have the permission to share the whole code. Could you instead give me a suggestion on how to return the selected date in ```showDatepicker```?, once i have that return type then i should be able to solve it from there :)

Comment: may be your _daysPageController is null

Comment: answer has been provided here : question has been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388315/the-method-jumptoday-was-called-on-null-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get date from DateTime object

```
  DateTime selecteddate = DateTime.now();
  Future<void> _selectDate() async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selecteddate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selecteddate){
      setState(() {
        selecteddate = picked;
      });
      if(_daysPageController != null){
        _daysPageController.jumpToDay(selecteddate);
      }
    }
  }
```