# The method 'jumpToDay' was called on null. [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

In this application, the user will be able to add tasks and display it in a `PageView.builder`. The user will also be able to scroll through the `PageView.builder` by swiping left or right. The pageview is mapped to dates (ex: current page maps to today's date, next page maps to tomorrow's date, etc.). I also wanted to implement a jump feature which lets the user move to a new page by specifying a date on a `showDatepicker` widget.

The `PageView.builder` was implemented by using this project. this project also has the jump to page feature : https://github.com/ZedTheLed/calendar_views

the `showDatepicker` is implemented in the method below. it is called by clicking on a `Raisedbutton`:

```
  _selectDate() async {
    final DateTime picker =await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2010),
        lastDate: DateTime(2040)
    );

    if (picker != null) {
      print(picker);
      return _daysPageController.jumpToDay(picker); // this method jumps the user to a selected date
//        Navigator.pop(context);

//        print(selectedDate);
//       await runJump(selectedDate);
//       return selectedDate;
    }
  }
```

when the user clicks on a date, the variable `DateTime picker` successfully returns the user-selected date in the print statement. But when i pass this value to the jumptopage method, it gives his error : `The method 'jumpToDay' was called on null.`

The `PageView.builder` is implemented in the code below :

```
  final List<DateTime> days;


Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton:    new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text("Jump To Today"),
        onPressed: () {
          _selectDate();
        },
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: widget.days.map(((day) => Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.00,
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.00

              ),
                  child: Starting_screen(_makeTextString(day)),  //this screen displays the tasks added by the user
                )
            ),
          ).toList()
      ),
    );
```

the method `_makeTextString` just modifies a `DateTime` value and returns it in a desirable format.

Could i get a suggestion on how to handle this error?

full project is available here : https://bitbucket.org/NotAnurag/todolist_restarted/src/master/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the user clicks on a date, the variable `DateTime` picker successfully returns the user-selected date in the print statement. But when I pass this value to the `jumptopage` method, it gives his error: "The method `jumpToDay` was called on null"

The problem that I see in the code is that `_daysPageController` is not initialized. IDE helpfully suggests various methods that you can call on `DaysPageController`, but the fact remains that it is declared, but no value is assigned to it (meaning that it is `null`):

```
DaysPageController _daysPageController;  // remains null unless assigned a value
```

Therefore, what the error is attempting to tell is that `jumpToDay(DateTime)` is called on `null` (which obviously does not have such a method). If you look at the stack trace a bit more explicit hint is buried in there:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'jumpToDay' was called on null.

Try to initialize the controller and see if it helps to resolve the issue.